# How to remove Red lines on Docusign Document

Tags: docusignapi

I am getting red lines like below

Demonstration Documents Only
Provided By  Docusign Online Signing Service

How can  i remove the above lines from Docusign  PDF?

Answer (score 1):

This text appears in the DocuSign DEMO environment purposely. There is no way to disable this red text at the top right of your documents. This text does not appear when you send envelopes in Production.

Answer (score 0):

It's a feature, not a bug. It indicates that you're using the demonstration / developer sandbox platform.

You can get a 30 day trial account which will not include the disclaimer. You can also purchase a production account.